# How to use for-loops and arrays in python to calculate error propagation

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a for loop to calculate error bars by using the derivative method. The formula is relatively simple, however I seem to be running into errors in my code with respect to vector/array sizes. There are a lot of defined vectors in my code, and I have checked the length of all of them. All of the inputs into the for-loop are 1x25 sized arrays.

I've tried changing the indices in the for loop from range(1,25) to range(0,24) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
# Creating vectors
dfdvg = np.zeros(25)
dfdxi0 = np.zeros(25)
sigsquare = np.zeros(25)
vgerr = vrs
xi0err = xi0s
Asq = np.zeros(25)
Bsq= np.zeros(25)
sig = np.zeros(25)

# calculating derivatives and error vectors
for i in range(0,24):
    dfdvg[i] = (np.multiply(rms[:,i],delta[:,i]))**-1
    dfdxi0[i] = -vr[:,i]/(vr[:,i]*(np.power(delta[:,i],2)))
    Asq[i] = np.power(np.multiply(dfdvg[i],vgerr[i]),2)
    Bsq[i] = np.power(np.multiply(dfdxi0[i],xi0err[i]),2)
    sigsquare[i] = Asq[i] + Bsq[i]
    sig[i] = np.power(sigsquare[i],0.5)

q = np.power(np.multiply(rms,delta),-1)
left = np.multiply(vg,q)
right = -(beta*H)/(3*(1+zeff))
```

What I want is the "sig" vector, representing the propagated error for each index.

Comment: what are vrs , xi0s , rms, vr ?

Comment: vr is a 1x25 length vector of velocities, and vrs contains the error for each index. xi0 is a 1x25 length vector of dipole moments, and xi0s contains the error for each index. rms is a 1x25 vector of radii, radius is the independant variable, so it does not have an error vector. I copied vrs and xi0s into new variables so it would be clear that they are indeed errors. Delta is also a 1x25 vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the dimensions of the array, the problem is in the shape. Unluckily you didn't write all your arrays. The point is, if you could just use arrays (25) instead of (1, 25), everything works fine:

```
vrs = np.random.rand(25)
vr = np.random.rand(25)
xi0s = np.random.rand(25)
rms = np.random.rand(25)
delta = np.random.rand(25)
vg = np.random.rand(25)

# Creating vectors
dfdvg = np.zeros(25)
dfdxi0 = np.zeros(25)
sigsquare = np.zeros(25)
vgerr = vrs
xi0err = xi0s
Asq = np.zeros(25)
Bsq= np.zeros(25)
sig = np.zeros(25)

# calculating derivatives and error vectors
for i in range(0,24):
    dfdvg[i] = (np.multiply(rms[i],delta[i]))**-1
    dfdxi0[i] = -vr[i]/(vr[i]*(np.power(delta[i],2)))
    Asq[i] = np.power(np.multiply(dfdvg[i],vgerr[i]),2)
    Bsq[i] = np.power(np.multiply(dfdxi0[i],xi0err[i]),2)
    sigsquare[i] = Asq[i] + Bsq[i]
    sig[i] = np.power(sigsquare[i],0.5)

q = np.power(np.multiply(rms,delta),-1)
left = np.multiply(vg,q)
```

(your last line of code seems unrelated)

So, in my opinion, your best option is to reshape your arrays:

```
vrs=vrs.reshape(25)
```